# Is there any way to get custom column/property value of sharepoint document using c#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-object-model

below code working fine and gives me list of all files into sharepoint site.

i get standard properties of file like `item.File.Author and item.File.ModifiedBy but not custom item.File.Location`

```
    // Sharepoint Object Model Code
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("siteurl"); 
    clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.Load(web.Lists);
    clientContext.Load(web, wb => wb.ServerRelativeUrl);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("My Doc");
    clientContext.Load(list);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"My Doc");
    clientContext.Load(folder);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                             <Query>
                             </Query>
                         </View>";
    camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    FileInformation fileInfo;

    foreach (var item in listItems)
    {
       // How to get File custom properties ? i.e Location , Path , Flat
       // I can get standard properties of file like - 
       // item.File.Author and item.File.ModifiedBy but not item.File.Location
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "Location","Path" value, we need use the code below:

```
var location=item["Location"];
var path=item["Path"];
```

[image]